# Android: Is it possible to read package name inside AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a question, is it possible to read package name inside AndroidManifest.xml

I mean

I have a AndroidManifest.xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackagename"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

....

</manifest>
```

Now I have to add a permission (used for GCM)

```
<permission
        android:name="MYPACKAGENAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Is it possible to replace MYPACKAGENAME with com.mypackagename dynamically in the above permission tag.

Comment: no. not that i know of. you might be able to store it in strings.xml however.

Comment: You cannot update manifest file dinamically.

Comment: AFAIK we cannot store access the package name even from string.xml or is it possible?

Comment: No you can not. And what is benefit to dynamically set?  Package name is not going to change the entire life of an application.

Comment: @Vinayak.B Let me know what are you trying to achieve. and what is your requirement so that I can help you

Comment: Can I ask Why do you need to change that?

Answer (score 28):

You can drop the package name part of the name:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackagename">
    ...

    <permission
        android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    ...
</manifest>
```

When you start your permission name with . it gets prefixed with package name automatically.

You cannot change package name dynamically, but you can do certain things by defining applicationId in build.gradle and then prefixing names in android manifest with ${applicationId}.

in build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.2"
    productFlavors {
       development {
           applicationId = "com.mypackage.development"
       }
    }
}
```

And then in your AndroidManifest.xml have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackagename">
    ...

    <permission
        android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    ...
</manifest>
```

You can find a bit more from here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger

Later approach will allow you to run development flavor of your app side by side your production version. I hope this helps.

Comment: Good question, I meet the same problem when to set package name to `android:host={packagename}` in the intent-filter

Comment: @miko Hey, can you confirm that is "When you start your permission name with . it gets prefixed with package name automatically." this true for every string I create inside AndroidManifest?

Comment: It would just solve a huge bulk of issues on my side. Is there any documentation pointing to this?

Comment: "However, as a shorthand, if the first character of the string is a period, the string is appended to the application's package name (as specified by the <manifest> element's package attribute). The following assignment is the same as the one above: ..."

Taken from: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html. So yes, it gets prefixed by the package name.

Comment: If you use applicationId, here is some additional documentation that you might find helpful: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

Comment: How about if i just need the package without any postfix? I guess . won't help me in my case?

Comment: Sorry @Vlad, but I don't understand what you try to achieve. Can you give an example?

Comment: @Vlad How did you get it?

Comment: @Boby In eclipse i've created a custom builder that helped me with this and a bunch more manifest manipulations i needed to do. Since then, i've moved to Android Studio and gradle and i do it with a variable from the build file.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `${applicationId}` to substitute your package name, eg.

```
<permission
        android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Answer (score 6):

An alternative not yet posted here is `"${packageName}"`. This is useful, for example if you're developing a library with a certain package name, but the application(s) using that library will have a different package name and/or application ID: `"${packageName}"` in the library's manifest will expand to the library's package name.

Answer (score 0):

you can uses a relative usage.

Static :

```
<permission
        android:name="com.mypackagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Relative :

```
<permission
        android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

when the name starts with dot is like to put MYPACKAGENAME declared in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackagename"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

....

</manifest>
```

Answer (score -1):

AndroidManifest.xml is (as its name suggests) for declaring and manifesting things.

Reading your package name dynamically within your application is possible because its declared in your manifest file.

Theoritically it's not possible to read or pass values inside your AndroidManifest. You will need to do the dynamic operations inside your application.

Answer (score -3):

Your answer is **NO**..

Once you **publish your application**, you cannot change the package name. The package name defines your application's identity, so if you change it, then it is considered to be a different application and users of the previous version cannot update to the new version.

**In other words**

Android considers application with different package name as different application altogether

**EDIT:**

Is it `Context.getPackageName()` you are looking for

Comment: My intention is not to edit it but to read it in same AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: you can get package name programatically but you cannot set or edit in ANdroid manifest file